# WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)

Tags: cron, apscheduler

In my code i run a cron job which is run for every five seconds, and I've been getting the same WARNING ever since.

this is the api that i used:

```
sched.add_cron_job(test_3, second="*/5")
```

And I get a warning:

```
WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job "test_3 (trigger: cron[second='*/5'], next run at: 2013-11-28 15:56:30)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
```

I tried giving time gap of 2 minutes it doesn't solve the issue.....
Help me in overcoming this issue..

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out it was just your job 'test_3' lasting too long, more then 5 secs (or 2 minutes as you tried).
APScheduler is trying to re-execute you job, but the previous one is still running.

Comment: YES the issue was the same as you say, i had to stop the thread 'test_3' each time before it could start again.
I used 'proc.terminate()' method to terminate the thread during the end of 5th second. And after that i stopped getting those error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I used the ***proc.terminate()*** to stop the execution of my method. So that the instance of the 1st thread is terminated before a new thread could start again.

Also provide a timing mechanism to complete your process well within the scheduled time say within a minute, hour or day etc. In my application i used ***sleep(in_seconds)*** for providing the timing mechanism.

Comment: Where should we use proc.terminate? could you show it in code?