# Maximum number of running instances reached (1) - apscheduler

Tags: python, apscheduler

I'm using apscheduler to recursively run a function in my application. The basic source of this functionality is as follows:

```
class ClassName(QtGui.QWidget)
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassName, self).__init__()

        from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
        sched = Scheduler(standalone=True)
        sched.daemonic = False
        sched.add_cron_job(self.FunctionName, second='*/5')

    def FunctionName(self):
        print("Hello World!")
        #Function contents here

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ClassName = ClassName()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My understanding from reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264298/warningapscheduler-schedulerexecution-of-job-skipped-maximum-number-of-runnin) thread, is that if the called function hasn't completed when the next job is started, the "Maximum number of running instances reached" error can be raised. I understand the theory behind the solution in that thread, but am unsure on the application.

Should I explicitly state, at the end of the called function, the terminate/kill a process to ensure that the original thread is removed before the next thread is started?

Comment: A few questions: 1) how are you using processes here? 2) I don't see any recursion here, so how does that apply here? 3) How come you don't use apscheduler 3 which has direct support for pyqt?

Comment: I'm not using processes, but thought I might have to as per the linked thread. The recursion is from adding the cron job, there is no recursion inherent to the actual function itself. I actually had trouble running apscheduler 3.x, so installed an earlier 2.x version.

Comment: I've just installed apscheduler 3 and it's working fine (user error on the first attempt it would seem). Ideally I'd like to delay the starting of the next scheduled function until the previous/current one finishes. Is this something that is supported natively with apscheduler, or would it require some manual intervention?

Comment: That is not supported natively. You can have your scheduled function schedule a new job though.

Comment: Thanks for that @AlexGrönholm, much appreciated. This is a really great library! I think I have this issue handled for the time being.