# APScheduler and Heroku: Execution of job skipped: Maximum number of running instances reached

Tags: python, heroku, apscheduler

There was a similar question posted here 3 years ago:

[WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264298/warningapscheduler-schedulerexecution-of-job-skipped-maximum-number-of-runnin)

But the question was never fully answered.

I have processes that execute every 3 hours.  I fire off my commands to update my database, but somehow they are not closing.  So in a few weeks I get the error "Execution of job skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1).   But at any rate, is there a way to terminate my commands so they free up and don't accumulate?

The original post suggests a command called proc.terminate.  What library is this from? How do I implement it in python?

For what it is worth, here is my schedule from APScheduler

```
@scheduler.scheduled_job('cron', hour='0,3,6,9,12,15,18')
def clock_scheduled_commands():
    print('Updating Tables')
    updatePrices.main()
    print('Updating Margins')
    calculateMargins.main()
    #print('Pushing to Perm')
    #PushToPerm.main()
    print(time.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
```

Note that the updatePrices.main() and calculateMargins.main() both return 0 indicating that they are complete.  They also both close the cursor at the end (as far as I can tell).

EDIT: Here is my Procfile for Heroku as requested:

```
web: gunicorn controller:app
clock: python scripts/clock.py
```

Comment: Two questions - 1) can you post your `Procfile` and 2) are you launching the scheduler (I assume it's a proc other than web) via Heroku scheduler, or scaling to 1 dyno for that type?

Comment: I have a separate clock dyno to trigger the events.  I am not using Heroku scheduler.

Comment: I tried running the queries manually in python, but they were hanging.  I flushed the connections and restarted the dynos and it worked again.  Is there a way to kill all connections when the clock process triggers?

Comment: The fact that killing the connections resolved it leads me to suspect an issue with transactions, either in `updatePrices` or `calculateMargins` - they're waiting for locks to clear. What db and framework (SQLAlchemy, etc.) are you using?

Comment: I am not using a framework. I am using psycopg2.

Comment: Any chance you can post some of that code (specifically, connection and cursor management)?

Answer (score 0):

in updatePrices and calculateMargins, I was opening and closing the cursor in each transaction.  I think this caused problems.